# Custom field in title

Tags: php, custom-field, filters, title

I'm trying to change the posts with no titles to 'custom field' + 'mystring'. So far I got this code.

```
        add_filter( 'the_title', 'ta_modified_post_title');
        function ta_modified_post_title ($title) {
        if( $title == $post->post_title and !is_page() ){
        $title = $title.$_POST['user-submitted-customfield'].'mystring';
        }
        return $title;
        }
```

However, the custom field does not get parsed. And it only changes the post titles in the backend (/wp-admin/edit.php says there are titles, but when I view the post it says none)

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to update these posts in the database, or just on the display side of things?

Comment: database .. oh that's not possible with the script?

Comment: No. Filters only modify the *output* of stored data; they do not modify those data directly. To modify the post title directly, you'll probably want to look into hooking into the `save_post` action or similar, and modifying the title before it is saved to the DB.